# ASP.NET UpdatePanel in UserControl doesn't trigger Click event

Tags: asp.net

I have set the following in my ascx file :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="from_dispo_to_affich" runat="server" OnClick="from_dispo_to_affich_Click"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My problem is that the OnClick event doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a javascript function call right?

Change OnClick to OnClientClick. And put () after your function.

```
 OnClientClick="from_dispo_to_affich_Click()"
```

Otherwise put this event in your codebehind

```
    protected void from_dispo_to_affich_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: No it's not a javascript function, it's a server side event.

Comment: Do you have put an event in your code behind? Like my new example?

Comment: Yes I did. Also tried adding UpdateMode="Conditional" and a trigger like this : <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ConrolID="from_dispo_to_affich" /></Triggers>

Comment: Ok than I need some more info, because I tested it and it works at my work environment. The trigger and the update mode status are not nessecary to let it work.

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with UserControl. If I remove the codebehind event, it will detect that it's not here but if I click on the button, click event is not executed.

Comment: In my console I get the following error when clicking on the button : "invalid postback or callback argument"

Comment: I had a javascrpt function that was modifying another control when I clicked on the button that was causing the error and my event not to be triggered.

Comment: Are you getting in your event when you remove the update panel?